# Excel VBA macro completes before cells on worksheet are refreshed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an issue with some Excel automation being used to create a dashboard. I have an Excel macro enabled workbook that also has data connections to an Access database. Every morning (Mon-Friday) another process automatically exports data to an Access database and then Excel connects to the necessary tables to show that data in charts and graphs.

My issue:
I'm using VBA to perform calculations on one of the charts that retrieves new data from a table produced by the data connection between Access and Excel. The idea is for the new day's data to be included in a calculation using the previous day's data. The new day's data is always the last cell with data in the column and the previous day's data is right above it in the same column. For some reason the new day's data does not get filled until AFTER the code below has finished executing. I've tried using **Worksheets("Worksheet'sName").Calculate** because the chart uses an IF statement to get data from the table generated by the data connection but it still doesn't work. I've also tried using a delay thinking that the code was running way too fast but the result was the same. Has anyone else come across this issue?

My code for this calculation:

```
Sub Differences(ByVal column As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Sheets
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim dailyDiff As Double
Dim busDayDiff As Double
Dim mtdDiff As Double

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Set wks = ws("Charts") 
wks.Activate

i = 4

wks.Range(column & i).Select

Do While Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
    i = i + 1
    wks.Range(column & i).Select
Loop

**dailyDiff = Selection.Value - Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Value** '<---The Calculation i'm referring to
busDayDiff = Selection.Value - Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value
mtdDiff = Selection.Value - wks.Range(column & "3").Value

ws.Range(column & "28") = busDayDiff
ws.Range(column & "29") = dailyDiff
ws.Range(column & "30") = mtdDiff

End Sub



Sub AllDifferences()

Differences ("b")
Differences ("d")
Differences ("f")
Differences ("h")
Differences ("j")
Differences ("l")

End Sub


Sub RefreshAll()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub test()

Call RefreshAll
Call AllDifferences

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm hoping *column* is supposed to be a letter. 
It's also a reserved word that could refer to the current Selection's column index number.

Comment: @Jeeped it's supposed to be a parameter of his main sub `Sub Differences(ByVal column As String)`. That said, I don't know how it resolves that when it's a keyword

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thats right. On the same note, I honestly wasn't thinking about it being a reserved word. I'll switch it to something else!

Answer (score 0):

A way to get around this issue is to put all subs, etc that you want to run after pulling the Access/Database data into a different sub. You must do this each time you call Access information. If you call another sub in the "master" sub after the Application.OnTime Now +TimeValue("00:00:15"), it will fail- you must put all subs following into a new master sub.

Comment: Thanks @madrac. So if I understand correctly in my master *sub test()*, I can only call RefreshAll in this scenario? (or any sub that doesn't need to utilize Access information)?